# WPF Toolkit: how to scroll datagrid to show selected item from code behind?

Tags: wpf, scroll, datagrid, selection, wpftoolkit

I tried the following, all of which fail on function ScrollIntoView and give a NullReferenceException:

```
// doesn't work
grid.SelectedItem = sItem;
grid.ScrollIntoView(sItem);

// doesn't work
grid.SelectedItem = sItem;
grid.Focus();
grid.CurrentColumn = grid.Columns[0];
grid.UpdateLayout();
grid.ScrollIntoView(sItem,grid.Columns[0]);

// doesn't work
grid.SelectedItem = sItem;
grid.UpdateLayout();
grid.ScrollIntoView(sItem);
```

The problem is, when I select a row from code-behind, selection is not visible - it's somewhere down the bottom. Unless the user scrolls they feels that selection has vanished. I need to scroll a DataGrid to the point that user can see the selection.

I also tried "BringIntoView" as well but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtualized Stack Panel didn't have an item container, because Item Container does not exist for the item outside the view and that's why this error was shown. Disabling virtualization resolves the issue for now, and the bug has been reported to codeplex toolkit project.

Answer (score 51):

Try:

```
grid.SelectedItem = sItem; 
grid.UpdateLayout();
grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: in first statement I am assigning grid.SelectedItem = sItem, do you think grid.SelectedItem and sItem are different in anyway?? sorry its wrong answer it will never work.

Comment: SelectedItem wrapper on a dependency property so my code is different to what you have. Give it a try, I had the same issue and this worked for me. 

See dissembly:

[Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden), Bindable(true)]
public object SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return base.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }
}

Comment: Akash, have you given this a go yet?