# WPF DataGrid - maintain scroll position after refresh

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll, refresh, wpfdatagrid

Anyone knows how to maintain the vertical scroll position after the Refresh command?

My Datagrid receives binding from a List of objects.

Many thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  I setup a simple WPF DataGrid and when I change the ItemsSource and/or trigger an Items.Refresh() the vertical scroll position seems to be maintained.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135544/reset-wpf-datagrid-scrollbar-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 posible solutions :

1) Try to update the list instead of replacing it. it means adding new items and removing items you don't need.

2) you can save the state of the scroller before refreshing and then scroll programmly to the selected item.

[WPF Toolkit: how to scroll datagrid to show selected item from code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984882/wpf-toolkit-how-to-scroll-datagrid-to-show-selected-item-from-code-behind)

Comment: I'm using the default WPF Datagrid. How can I save the state of the vertical scroller?

Comment: See the answer to this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770487/access-scrollview-properties-of-a-datagrid-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is what I did:

1. Find the `ScrollViewer` of your `Datagrid`/`ListBox` when it is leaded and add a `ScrollChanged` event:

```
var scrollViewer = FindScrollViewer(ListBoxOrders);
if (scrollViewer != null)
{
    scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += scrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
}
//Here is the function to find the ScrollViewer:
private ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject d)
{
    if (d is ScrollViewer)
        return d as ScrollViewer;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d); i++)
    {
        var sw = FindScrollViewer(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i));
        if (sw != null) return sw;
    }
    return null;
}
```

2. On scroll changed, store the vertical offset:

```
private double _verticalOffset;
private void scrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    _verticalOffset = sv.VerticalOffset;
}
```

3. After refresh, scroll to the previous position:

```
scrollViewer?.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_verticalOffset);
```